# Using select statement to delete rows

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have the below query:

```
SELECT a.* FROM id_stats a
join id_list b
on a.id = b.id
and a.start_date NOT between b.start_date::date and DATEADD(day,7,b.start_date::date)
```

that returns the rows I want to see from the id_stats table, but when I try to delete I get an error:

```
DELETE a FROM id_stats a
join id_list b
on a.id = b.id
and a.start_date NOT between b.start_date::date
and DATEADD(day,7,b.start_date::date)
```

error:

> SQL compilation error: syntax error line 1 at position 7 unexpected
> 'a'. syntax error line 2 at position 0 unexpected 'join'.

Comment: get rid of the 'a' that is after the DELETE.  Also, are you sure you're running just one query?  I don't even see a JOIN on line 2.

Comment: @MikeWalton I've updated to have JOIN on line 2, I think snowflake mentioned something about delete statement having USING so I tried that. I tried with JOIN but I see: syntax error line 2 at position 0 unexpected 'join'.

Comment: @MikeWalton also I've tried with DELETE FROM id_stats.. etc. but I see the same error

Comment: the correct syntax should be something more like this:  DELETE FROM id_stats a
using id_list b
where a.id = b.id
and a.start_date NOT between b.start_date::date
and DATEADD(day,7,b.start_date::date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the comments above, here is the reference document that explains the syntax.  No `JOIN` and no `ON`.  It's `using` and `where`.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/delete.html#syntax

```
DELETE FROM id_stats a 
 using id_list b 
 where a.id = b.id 
   and a.start_date NOT between b.start_date::date and DATEADD(day,7,b.start_date::date)
```